# Как "true" и "false" значения конвертировать в "Да" и "Нет" соответственно?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Добрый вечер!
Есть таблица в БД, в ней есть атрибут "Х" с типом boolean (значения, соответственно, может принимать true или false).
Таблица отображается с помощью bootstrapTable, и столбец "Х" выглядит след. образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно вывести значения атрибута по-другому: либо чтобы вместо true было "Да" (false  - "Нет"), либо чтобы были checkbox?
Я пыталась искать что-то подобное, но не нашла.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664202/5640806

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047881/5640806

Comment: Ну и насчет checkbox'а - https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Comment: @Colibri когда указываете аналогичные вопросы на большом SO, по возможности [используйте формат **ассоциации**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/181100) -- это позволит русскоязычным посетителям SO видеть аналогичный вопрос на русском. Впрочем, для вопросов без хорошего ответа в ассоциации нет большого смысла :)

Comment: @D-side хорошо. В будущем учту это.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хелпер в помощь

```
def booleanize(value)
  value ? 'Да' : 'Нет'
end
```

и в вьюхе

```
<%= booleanize(@record.boolean) %>
```

Можно без хелпера во вьюхе вставить это дело но не красиво

```
<%= @record.boolean ? 'Да' : 'Нет' %>
```